# How can i pass multiple parameters in location.href in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

example (this is not working)

```
location.href = 'freecreate?fname=+fname+"&Mnumber="+Mnumber+"&sitename="+sitename';
```

Comment: use an ide with a syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add double quotes(") after fname= , Use this:

```
location.href = "freecreate?fname="+fname+"&Mnumber="+Mnumber+"&sitename="+sitename;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with **php** variables just Declare them, 
assign values and append them

using `.` operator

See the example below:

```
<?php 

    $fname="bhansa";
    $Mnumber ="number";
    $sitename ="stack";
    echo "<script>window.location = 'freecreate?fname=".$fname."+&Mnumber=".$Mnumber."+&sitename=".$sitename."'</script>";

?>
```

Use @Dhara Parmar's method if you want to use in javascript.